# Pass Contest Id into URL for search in Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url

I have two models, contest and submission. **submission** belongs_to contest and **contest** has_many submissions.

In the index action for submissions I have a search:

```
def index
   contest_id = params[:contest_id]
   @contest = Contest.find(contest_id)
   if params[:search].blank?
      @submissions = Submission.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
   else
      @submissions = Submission.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
   end
      @search = params[:search] 
end
```

I think the right way to pass it in is through the search form in the submissions>index view:

```
<div class ="span12 row">
    <%= form_tag submissions_path, :method => 'get', :class => "form-search pull-right" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'input-xlarge', :placeholder => 'Search by member, title or description' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :title => nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

And I have been able to come close using this:

```
<%= hidden_field :contest_id, @contest.id %>
```

In the form, but it's returning this in the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/submissions?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=test&contest_id%5B%5D=&commit=Search
```

And an error:

```
Couldn't find Contest with id=
```

I've also tried this:

```
<%= hidden_field(:contest_id, :value => @contest.id ) %>
```

But it's returning similar url and error.

Right now, I'm stuck. If you have any idea, please let me know.

[edit - added html]

Before search:

```
<div class ="span12 row">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/submissions" class="form-search pull-right" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
       <input class="input-xlarge" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search by member, title or description" type="text" />
       <input id="contest_id_5" name="contest_id[5]" type="hidden" />
       <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's what works from other links going to submissions:

From the submission show page:

```
<%= link_to 'Browse All Submissions', submissions_path(:contest_id => @contest.id), :class => 'btn btn-mini pull-right' %>`
```

and from the contest show page:

```
<%= link_to 'Browse All Submissions', submissions_path(:contest_id => @contest.id), :class => 'btn btn-mini pull-right' %>
```

Both of these pass the url "contest_id=5" which is what the controller needs to find a contest. The issue I'm having with search is finding the right syntax to get contest_id=5 to appear without the mumbo jumbo mucking it up.

Comment: please show your generated html code with the link

Comment: @Lichtamberg I added the html output to the question at bottom.

Comment: What do your routes look like? Are you using nested resources?

Comment: @gcastro Nested routes would make it too complex because of polymorphic comment model that's tied into a Redis store for email notifications. I have all the standard routes generated by `resources submissions`.

Comment: You can have submissions nested without nesting comments though.

Comment: @gcastro Are you saying it can't be done without nesting? Nesting messes with `as commentable`, which tracks what model is being commented on, so nesting, unfortunately, will not work. Every submission knows what contest it belongs to, so for show it's simple, but index needs to know what contest from the start. I have added a "what works" section to the bottom of the question to illustrate. I think the issue is finding the right syntax for search.

Comment: Just wanted to check if there was a reason for not going with nested resources (which you do have). Any reason for actually sending the contest_id? If you're searching for submissions they should know the contest they belong to through their association.

Comment: @gcastro The issue I'm having is how to pass the value into the url for use on the following page, not the ability to find the contest_id on the current page. It's a syntax thing and what function to attach it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an easy solution. Insert a hidden_field_tag in the search form:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'contest_id', @contest.id %>
```

This will pass the correct value into params:

```
 http://localhost:3000/submissions?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=new&contest_id=5&commit=Search
```